# Get Column B value from Column A from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Thanks in advance My question is detailed described below

I have two columns named as User Name and User Id in sheet A and Sheet B

Sheet A User Name Column is dropdown which I am referring from SheetB, if the user select any user name from SheetA dropdown, the associated User Id from Sheet B will be displayed in SheetA user Id column

This is sheet A:

[image: This is sheet A]

This is my sheet B:

[image: This is my sheet B]

Comment: If you are looking for a simple Vlookup formula why do you have `google-apps-script` in the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `SheetA`, cell `G2`, you can use the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(if(len(F2:F),vlookup(F2:F,'Sheet B'!A2:B,2,false),))`

It will automatically update for the cells below in that column

For more information, see [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)